# hibernate 5.2.2: db translation logic

Tags: java, hibernate

I 'm trying to learn through a few examples the db transaltion logic and understand how this db can be change using entity annotation:[DB example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaj1u.png)
I put 1,N and N,N reletions inside the logic problem and I translate like this in the previous schema, with:

Model 0,N Article , Article 1,1 Model.

User 0,N Cart , Cart 1,1 User.

Article 0,N Cart, Cart 1,1 Article.

I created the most part of the class and the main, but the part of build relationships stops me.
This is my situation:

Model:

```
@Entity   
@Table(name = "MODEL") 
public class Model{
   private int id;
   private double cost;
   private double price;

   public model(int id,double cost,double price){
         this.id=id;
         this.cost=cost;
         this.price=price;
   }

   @Id
   @Column(name="idModel")
   public void setId(int id){this.id=id;}
   public int getId(){return id;}

   @Column(name="cost")
   public void setCost(double cost){this.cost=cost;}
   public double getCost(){return cost;}

   @Column(name="price")
   public void setPrice(double price){this.price=price;}
   public double getPrice(){return price;}
}
```

Article:

```
@Entity   
@Table(name = "ARTICLE")
public class Article{
   private int id;
   private String code;
   private int quantity;
   private Model thisModel;

   public Article(int id, String code, int quantity, Model model){
      this.id=id;
      this.code=code;
      this.quantity=quantity;
      thisModel=model;
   }

   @Id
   @Column(name="idArticle")
   public void setId(int id){this.id=id;}
   public int getId(){return id;}

   @Column(name="code")
   public void setCode(String code){this.code=code;}
   public String getCode(){return code;}

   @Column(name="quantity")
   public void setQuantity(int quantity){this.quantity=quantity;}
   public int getQuantity(){return quantity;}

   @Column(name="model_idModel")
   public void setModel(Model model){this.model=model;}
   public Model getModel(){return model;}
}
```

User:

```
@Entity   
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User{
   private int id
   private String name;

   public User(int id,String name){
      this.id=id;
      this.name=name;
   }

   @Id
   @Column(name="idUser")
   public void setId(int id){this.id=id;}
   public int getId(){return id;}

   @Column(name="name")
   public void seName(String name){this.name=name;}
   public int getName(){return name;}
}
```

Cart:

```
@Entity   
@Table(name = "CART")
public class Cart   {
   private User user;
   private Article article;

   publi Cart(User user,Article article){
      this.user=user;
      this.article=article;
   }

   @Id
   @Column(name="idUser")
   public void setUser(User user){this.user=user;}
   public User getUser(){return user;}

   @Id
   @Column(name="idArticle")
   public void setArticle(Article article){this.article=article;}
   public User getArticle(){return article;}
}
```

Main:

```
public class test(){   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SessionFactory factory = new    Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      Session session=factory.getCurrentSession();
      Transaction transaction = null;
      try {
         transaction = session.beginTransaction();
         Model m1= new Model (1,12,24);
         Model m2= new Model (2,40,88);
         Article a1m1 = new Article(1,"blue",200,m1);
         Article a2m1 = new Article(2,"rad",100,m1);
         Article a1m2 = new Article(1,"only green",2000,m2);
         User u1 = new User(1,"Max");
         User u2 = new User(2,"Ada");
         Set<Cart> Carts = new HashSet<Cart>();
         carts.add(new Cart(u1,a2m1));
         carts.add(new Cart(u2,a1m2));
         session.save(a1m1);
         session.save(a2m1);
         session.save(a1m2);
         session.save(u1);
         session.save(u2);
         session.save(Carts);
         transaction.commit();
      } catch (HibernateException e) {
         transaction.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         session.close();
      }
   }
}
```

I also believe that my main is not perfect, and at run/compaile would give me some problems, and I have lost some logic concept in this db translation.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: if you run my code is a far from what I expect, miss all the association mapping between classes,so the code is incomplete. I need to understand how to solve it, and why a solution in place of an other

Comment: @Francesco The code is incomplete, where did you decide what database you like to use? I expect MySQL or PostgreSQL or Hypersonic but i found none of them.

Comment: @Peter Rader I use mySQL but i don't write the hibernate.cfx.xml because I'm a step backward compared to the implementation of this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotations for relations differs from annotations for non-relational columns. Use `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` instead of `@Column` for relation-columns.

Do not ask why, using `@Column` let hibernate think that the complex type shall map the column, not its relation.